# Reading from file (require)

Tags: php, require

I have something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKLK2.png and im currently working on "admin" folder and inside of that i have "admin.php", but the problem is that i want to read "core/init.php" from there. Now i have this in admin.php

```
<?php
require '../includes/header.php';
?>

<?php
$user = new User();
if(!$user->isLoggedIn()){
    Redirect::to(404);
}
else if(!$user->hasPermission('admin')){
    Redirect::to(404);
}
?>
<div id="content">

</div>

<?php
require '../includes/footer.php';
?>
```

And inside the "includes/header.php" i have php require_once 'core/init.php'; but i get this for my admin page:

```
Warning: require(core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\includes\header.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'core/init.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\includes\header.php on line 2
```

I know i have to add `../` but then i get that error on my index.php page which must be run without that because its not inside the folder, it only runs header and footer from includes folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) explains:

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the `include_path` specified.
>
> ...
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the `include_path` will be ignored altogether.

#### How this applies to your code?

`require_once 'core/init.php';` - PHP searches all the paths from the `php.ini` directive `include_path`. It appends `core/init.php` to each path from the list and checks if the path computed this way exists. Most probably it doesn't.

`require_once './core/init.php';` - `include_path` doesn't matter; the provided relative path (`core/init.php`) is appended to the current directory to get the path of the file;

#### What's the solution?

None of the above ways actually works in practice.

The safest method to include files using subdirectories is to use the magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and the function [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to compute the correct file path.

```
require '../includes/header.php';
```

becomes

```
require dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/header.php';
```

and

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
```

becomes

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/core/init.php';
```

because `__DIR__` is the directory where the current file (`includes/header.php`) is located.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use **`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`** instead of **"../"** I think that will solve your issue about require operation.

```
<?php
require ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/includes/header.php');
?>

<?php
$user = new User();
if(!$user->isLoggedIn()){
    Redirect::to(404);
}
else if(!$user->hasPermission('admin')){
    Redirect::to(404);
}
?>
<div id="content">

</div>

<?php
require ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/includes/footer.php');
?>
```

You can find reference about DOCUMENT_ROOT key here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -1):

Define in your `header.php` `HEADER_DIR` based on `__FILE__` variable. Where `__FILE__` is one of php's magic constants see here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

```
define('HEADER_DIR', dirname(__FILE__)); 

// then use it in all includes 
require HEADER_DIR . "/../core/init.php";
require HEADER_DIR . "../some_other_folder/some_file.php";
```